# What is the best practices of ETL pipeline using Luigi python package?

Tags: python, data, pipelines, etl

I am looking more for concepts or pointed in the right direction for best practices for a project I am working on. I am currently playing around with [Luigi](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package for the **[ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) pipeline**.

I followed the tutorial: [Python: Create an ETL with Luigi, Pandas and SQLAlchemy](https://kpatronas.medium.com/python-create-an-etl-with-luigi-pandas-and-sqlalchemy-d3cdc9292bc7)

This was easy enough to get up and running. Where I am struggling conceptually is if I run this pipeline *nightly*.

What is the best practice for handling data new or changing data from the source data?

- Question 1) Should you be gathering a full dataset from Source, and then overwriting the data at the Target? Or is it better to try and only insert new records? Ie. The difference between Source and Target.
- Question 2) If you are only inserting new records, what is the best practice for handling updated records? Is it better to capture the whole record with a date on it? Or am I updating the record that sits in the Target?